# Is this proof regarding boundary and closed sets correct?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-verification

I've tried to prove the following: Let $A\subset \mathbb{R}^n$, then $A$ is closed if and only if $\partial A\subset A$. My proof is as follows:

Notice first that we always have $\partial A \subset \operatorname{Cl}(A)$, because $p \in \partial A$ implies that every ball $B(p;r)$ contains points of $A$ and of $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus A$, hence it contains non-empty intersection with $A$ and hence $p \in \operatorname{Cl}(A)$. Now, if $A$ is closed, $A = \operatorname{Cl}(A)$ and hence $\partial A \subset A$.

Suppose now that $\partial A \subset A$, since we want to show that $A$ is closed, we are going to show that $\mathbb{R}^n \setminus A$ is open. Consider $p \in \mathbb{R}^n \setminus A$, then $ p \notin A$ and hence by hypothesis $p \notin \partial A$. So, since a point is in $\partial A$ implies that every open ball $B(p;r)$ contains points of $A$ and of $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus A$ it must be the case that there is a ball $B(p;r)$ without points of $A$ or without points of $\mathbb{R}^n \setminus A$. Since $p \in \mathbb{R}^n \setminus A$ and the ball is centered at $p$, the second possibility is always impossible, every ball will have at least the point $p \in \mathbb{R}^n \setminus A$, so there must be the cases that exists an open ball $B(p;r)$ without points of $A$, and thus $B(p;r)\subset \mathbb{R}^n\setminus A$ showing that $A$ is closed since the complementary is open.

Since the proof was too simple I felt that it could be wrong. Is this proof ok? Is there something wrong with it? Thanks very much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof is perfect.

Note that $\text{cl}(A)=A\cup\partial A=A\cup A^d=\text{int}(A)\sqcup\partial A$, so you could also first show that equality (especially the first one), then the proof is even shorter.

By $A^d$ we mean the set of limit points of $A$. A point $x$ is called a *limit point* of $A$ if each ball around $x$ contains a point of $A$ other than $x$. A point $x\notin A$ is a limit point of $A$ iff it's a point in $\partial A$.